# Clean coding best practise for i loop with if statements

Tags: javascript

I want to clean my code up. I'm using a for I loop and using alot of if statements. What is the best way to clean this code up?

```
 for (let i = 0; i < 100 ; i++) {

     if (file_1h[i] == null) {
         console.log("Null detected and deleted");
         delete file_1h[i];
     }

     if (file_20h[i] == null) {
         console.log("Null detected and deleted");
         delete file_20h[i];
     }

     if (file_20d[i] == null) {
        console.log("Null detected and deleted");
        delete file_20d[i];
     }

     if (file_40y[i] == null) {
        console.log("Null detected and deleted");
         delete file_40y[i];
     }
}
```

Comment: Please include enough code that reviewers can run it. The additional context (e.g. what is `file_1h[i]`) will also help reviewers recommend how to improve your code.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question lacks any indication of what the code is intended to achieve. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, you can reuse the console.log and delete by putting them in a function. I don't have all the data in order to run the code, but this is one approach of refactor.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

  deleteIfNull(file_1h[i]);
  deleteIfNull(file_20h[i]);
  deleteIfNull(file_20d[i]);
  deleteIfNull(file_40y[i]);
}

function deleteIfNull(element) {
  if (element == null) {
    console.log("Null detected and deleted");
    delete element;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note: questions containing small snippets of code (and with little description of what the code does or how it is used) are off-topic on this site. If the OP edits their post to address the problem and make their post on-topic, they make your answer moot. [It is advised not to answer such questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6389/120114). Protip: There are tons of on-topic questions to answer; you'll make more reputation faster if you review code in questions that will get higher view counts for being on-topic.